# Jenkins scripted pipeline NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'setLatestRevision' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Could you please assist me, where am I wrong in this code?

Pipeline script below:

```
def executeShInEnvironment = { String shFunction, String parameters ->
    sh '. $SCRIPTS_DIR/build_functions.sh; ' + shFunction + " " + parameters
}

def setLatestRevision = { String parameters ->
    executeShInEnvironment('GET_LAST_REVISION', parameters)
}

def buildApp(svnRootUrl, propertiesDir, propertiesFileName) {
    def String fromRevisionPropertiesKey = "LAST_REVISION_FOR_02"
    def String toRevisionPropertiesKey = "CURRENT_SVN_REVISION"
    def String svnPath = svnRootUrl + "/svn_path"

    echo "Find latest SVN revision"
    withEnv(['SVN_URL=' + svnPath ]) {
        def shFunctionParameters = propertiesFileName + " " + toRevisionPropertiesKey
        setLatestRevision(shFunctionParameters)           
    }
}

def prepareRun(shellSvn, propertiesSvn) {
    stage 'Prepare run'
         .... do checkouts
}

node
{ 
    def workspace = pwd()
    def String shellSvn = "/shell"
    def String propertiesSvn = "/property_files"
    def String propertiesDir =  workspace + propertiesSvn
    def String scriptsDir = workspace + shellSvn
    def String svnRootUrl = "http://SVN_URL_goes_here"
    def String propertiesFileName = "main_delivery.properties"

    prepareRun(shellSvn, propertiesSvn)

    withCredentials(............... {
        withEnv(...........){
            buildApp(svnRootUrl, propertiesDir, propertiesFileName)
        }    
    }    
}
```

Why script says, that he can't see `setLatestRevision` method?

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'setLatestRevision'
>   found among steps

Not working method definition

```
setLatestRevision = { String parameters ->
```

**Working method**

```
setLatestRevision(String parameters) {
```

Can someone explain why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `setLatestRevision` is a variable (closure):

```
setLatestRevision = { String parameters ->
```

In the second case it is a method:

```
setLatestRevision(String parameters) {
```

The [Script class documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class) states (in the last section **3.4 Variables**) that:

*if the variable is declared as in the first example [with a type definition], it is a local variable. It will be declared in the run method that the compiler will generate and will not be visible outside of the script main body. In particular, such a variable will not be visible in other methods of the script*

And further: *if the variable is undeclared, it goes into the script binding. The binding is visible from the methods [...]*

Therefore removing the `def` from `setLatestRevision` fixes the error:

```
def executeShInEnvironment = { String shFunction, String parameters ->
    sh '. $SCRIPTS_DIR/build_functions.sh; ' + shFunction + " " + parameters
}

setLatestRevision = { String parameters ->
    executeShInEnvironment('GET_LAST_REVISION', parameters)
}

def buildApp(svnRootUrl, propertiesDir, propertiesFileName) {
    def String fromRevisionPropertiesKey = "LAST_REVISION_FOR_02"
    def String toRevisionPropertiesKey = "CURRENT_SVN_REVISION"
    def String svnPath = svnRootUrl + "/svn_path"

    echo "Find latest SVN revision"
    withEnv(['SVN_URL=' + svnPath ]) {
        def shFunctionParameters = propertiesFileName + " " + toRevisionPropertiesKey
        setLatestRevision(shFunctionParameters)           
    }
}

def prepareRun(shellSvn, propertiesSvn) {
    stage 'Prepare run'
         .... do checkouts
}

node
{ 
    def workspace = pwd()
    def String shellSvn = "/shell"
    def String propertiesSvn = "/property_files"
    def String propertiesDir =  workspace + propertiesSvn
    def String scriptsDir = workspace + shellSvn
    def String svnRootUrl = "http://SVN_URL_goes_here"
    def String propertiesFileName = "main_delivery.properties"

    prepareRun(shellSvn, propertiesSvn)

    withCredentials(............... {
        withEnv(...........){
            buildApp(svnRootUrl, propertiesDir, propertiesFileName)
        }    
    }    
}
```